# what is the best way to css-style cakephp pagination results

Tags: css, cakephp, pagination

what is the best way to style search pagination results.

Lets say your search results prices must be in red, 
item names in caps and bold, 
addresses in italic and on the right side of the page,

how do you style the pagination results - do you include the

or you have special CSS file for styling the search results

Answer (score 0):

Use css classes...and there is nothing special in styling this part (pagination) of the website...